# How to have nested maps of an array without the key prop warning?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, nested

I have an array of data:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    title: "title1",
    content: [
      {
        id: "home",
        name: "Home",
      },
      {
        id: "services",
        name: "services",
      },
      {
        id: "Appointments",
        name: "Appointments",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "title2",
    content: [
      {
        id: "about us",
        name: "about us",
      },
      {
        id: "contact",
        name: "contact",
      },
      {
        id: "blog",
        name: "blog",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to map through all of it.
I've tried using `nested maps` and adding `key prop` to each tag

```js
{arr.map((element) => (
          <div key={element.name}>
            <h4 key={element.name}>{element.title}</h4>
            <ul key={element.name}>
              {element.content.map((index) => (
                <li key={index.id}>
                  {index.name}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))}
```

I've tried using `nested maps` and it works fine and shows the array but I got this warning

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

How should I solve this warning?

Answer (score 0):

```
{arr.map((element , index) => (     // added index 
      <div key={index}>
        <h4 key={element.name}>{element.title}</h4>
        <ul key={element.name}>
          {element.content.map((index) => (
            <li key={index.id}>
              {index.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    ))}
```

This Adds index to array map.

Comment: The warning changed: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

When any loop or nested loop begins `key={index}` should be placed in the `parent element tag.`
**It should work:**

```js
{arr.map((element,index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <h4>{element.title}</h4>
            <ul>
              {element.content.map((item,index2) => (
                <li key={index2}>
                  {item.name}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        ))}
```